# Error propagation with a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, error-analysis

The following is a 2018 F=ma exam question. I know that this isn't a homework site, but I think that my question is conceptually relevant. Here's the problem:

> A group of students wish to measure the acceleration of gravity with a simple pendulum. They take one length measurement of the pendulum to be $l = 1.00 \pm 0.05\ \rm m$. They then measure the period of a single swing to be $T = 2.00 \pm 0.10\ \rm s$. Assume that all uncertainties are Gaussian. The computed acceleration of gravity from this experiment illustrating the range of possible values should be recorded as
>
> A) $9.87 \pm 0.10\ \rm{m/s^2}$
>
> B) $9.87 \pm 0.15\ \rm{m/s^2}$
>
> C) $9.9 \pm 0.25\ \rm{m/s^2}$
>
> D) $9.9 \pm 1.1\ \rm{m/s^2}$
>
> E) $9.9 \pm 1.5\ \rm{m/s^2}$

I know that the pendulum period formula is $T = 2\pi\sqrt{l/g}$, and therefore, that $g = \frac{4\pi^2l}{T^2}$

I don't know much about this error stuff, so I went about it in a fairly straightforward way and I still can't seem to find the flaw:

Obviously the biggest value for $g$ will be when $l$ is biggest and $T$ is smallest. The biggest $l$ is $1.00 + 0.05 = 1.05$. The smallest $T$ is $2.00 - 0.10 = 1.90$. $4\pi^2\times 1.05/(1.90)^2 = 11.48$.

The smallest value for $g$ is when $l$ is smallest and $T$ is biggest. Going through the same process, you get $g = 8.50$. The difference between those two values is  $2.97$ which is about $3$. Therefore, the error has to be something $\pm 1.5$, which would make the answer E. It is not E, but D.

The solution on the F=ma website said complicated things about adding squares of error and things I haven't learned.

So my question is what is wrong with my logic here?

Comment: Acvording to what you have provided, the answer is indeed E and not D

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your method is that it implicitly assumes the errors are (anti)correlated. Well, what does *that* mean?

It means you assume that when the length fluctuates high (low), then the period measurement *must* fluctuate low (high). Since a larger (smaller) length and a shorter (longer) time both increase (decrease) the value of $g$, the fluctuations in $g$ are overestimated.

The question then is, how do you add uncorrelated errors? Answer: in quadrature. The next question is, why in quadrature? You could write books on that, but in short, it's the Pythagorean theorem:

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$

which is exactly how you add uncorrelated lengths.

A somewhat loose explanation is, suppose:

$$ C = AB $$

and you measure:

$$ A \pm a $$

and

$$ B \pm b $$

What is the uncertainty in $C$?

Well, gaussian errors are distributed as:

$$ P_a(a) \propto e^{-a^2} $$

and

$$ P_b(b) \propto e^{-b^2}$$

so that:

$$ P_c(a, b) \propto P_a(a)P_b(b) $$
$$ P_c(a, b) = e^{-a^2}e^{-b^2} = e^{-(a^2+b^2)}\equiv e^{-c^2} =P_c(c) $$

where the fluctuations in $C$ given by those in $A$ and $B$ added in quadrature:

$$ c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

Comment: But when you want to describe the range of possibility, don't you want to consider the worst case?

Comment: @QFTUNIverse When you quote a 1 sigma error bar made from 1 sigma errors, you want exactly that: a 1 sigma variance--not the worst case. Now I have worked projects were we have included 99-percentile cases (1% chance), but then you're doing quantiles, and it's a bit more complicated. BTW: on 2nd thought, my "loose" explanation is too loose (unless $A=B$).

Answer (score 2):

When you give a measurement result with an extended standard uncertainty, you set a probability that the "true" value is in your range. For example, the probability that the true value of $l$ is between 0.95 and 1.05 is 95%. Or, the probability that the value is not in this range is 5%. Same idea for $T$.

As a result, your calculation is too pessimistic. You put yourself in the situation for which the errors would be maximum on both $l$ and on $T$ which is "unlikely". Without accurate calculation, you can understand that the probability that the true value of $g$ is outside your range is less than 5%. This is the reason why, most often, it is the squares of uncertainties that are added.

Answer (score 1):

An error equation is obtained from the differential of the equation. Take the differential operator of both sides and you get:

dg = 4 pi^2 (dI/T^2 - 2IdT/T^3)

dg/g = dI/I - 2dT/T

As we are after the magnitude of errors, the negative sign gets switched for a plus. There's a bit more to it but with uncorrelated guassian errors it works out smoothly. The equation is then one of relative errors.

Comment: As I said in my question, I know basically nothing about error propagation. My question was less about the proper solution and more about what is wrong with the method I was using.

Comment: Methodology wise you were looking at maximum and minimum errors. The key is that the errors are guassian so don't have a min/max but a variance.